# How to handle navigation with observables using Rx-MVVM-C

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Hello I am trying to do a project with RxSwift and I am stuck trying to do in a properly way the connection between the Coordinator and the ViewModel.

**Goal**

Using observables, the **Coordinator** receives and **event** (in that case, when a row has been tapped) then *does whatever*.

**Scenario**

Giving a **Post** (String)

```
typealias Post = String
```

I have the following **Coordinator**:

```
class Coordinator {

    func start() {

        let selectedPostObservable = PublishSubject<Post>()

        let viewController = ViewController()
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        viewController.viewModel = viewModel

        selectedPostObservable.subscribe { post in
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

The **selectedPostObservable** is what I don't know how to connect it in a "clean" way with the viewModel.

As **ViewModel**:

```
class ViewModel {

    struct Input {
        let selectedIndexPath: Observable<IndexPath>
    }

    struct Output { 
        //UI Outputs
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let posts: [Post] = Observable.just(["1", "2", "3"])

        //Connect with selectedindex
        let result = input.selectedIndexPath
            .withLatestFrom(posts) { $1[$0.row] }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)

        return Output()
    }
}
```

The **result** variable is what I should connect with  **selectedPostObservable**.

And the **ViewController** (although I think is not relevant for the question):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //...
    var viewModel: ViewModel!
    var tableView: UITableView!
    //...

    func bindViewModel() {
        let input = ViewModel.Input(selectedIndexPath: tableView.rx.itemSelected.asObservable())
        viewModel.transform(input: input)
    }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can pass to your ViewModel an instance of coordinator: `let viewModel = ViewModel(coordinator: self)` or the `PublishSubject` and have the coordinator observe it, but I think option one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the structure you are starting with, I would put the PublishSubject in the ViewModel class instead of the Coordinator. Then something like this:

```
class ViewModel {

    struct Input {
        let selectedIndexPath: Observable<IndexPath>
    }

    struct Output { 
        //UI Outputs
    }

    let selectedPost = PublishSubject<Post>()
    let bag = DisposeBag()

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let posts: [Post] = Observable.just(["1", "2", "3"])

        //Connect with selectedindex
        input.selectedIndexPath
            .withLatestFrom(posts) { $1[$0.row] }
            .bind(to: selectedPost)
            .disposed(by: bag)

        return Output()
    }
}

class Coordinator {

    func start() {

        let viewController = ViewController()
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        viewController.viewModel = viewModel

        viewModel.selectedPost.subscribe { post in
            //Do whatever
        }
        .disposed(by: viewModel.bag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I am gonna try it and let you know. Thanks Daniel!